# RPi Pico - write to flash in Rust

Tags: rust, embedded, raspberry-pi-pico

Im experimenting with RPi Pico and Rust. Im using rp2040-hal which has rom functions, including for writing to flash. For writing to flash you need to run the code from ram and not flash. To put the code in ram I think I need to use linker script. I have never written a linker script and I have no idea how would a linker script for copying code to ram looked like.

If the code gets too large you probably don't want to copy it to ram, only functions for writing to flash right? How can I do that?

Comment: Its unlikely you need to run from ram to be able to write to flash. Usually, you will define a section in your linker script for the area you want to write values into flash.

Comment: How to do that? Just make a section and thats it?